# How to add and update excel sheets in a selenium bot on heroku?

Tags: python, selenium, heroku

I am working on a selenium project which I am going to deploy on Heroku. I know all concepts and I already deployed a test selenium bot and all is working fine.

My idea here is to read some links from an excel file and use it in selenium. This excel file needs to be updated from time to time so it is not like that once we updated the sheet then our work is done. Now my question is how to do that. How can we deploy that updated sheet time to time .

**This is the test app-**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import random
import os

#url = "https://youtube.com"
url = input("Please enter the url of youtube.com")

op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.binary_location = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN')
op.add_argument("--headless")
op.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
op.add_argument("--disable-dev-sh-usage")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = os.environ.get('CHROMEDRIVER_PATH'),chrome_options = op)
driver.get("https://youtube.com")
print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: you should run code in some loop and in every loop check if file has new date of creation - `os.stat(path)`. OR if you run code in loop then in every loop read file again to get new data.

Comment: if you ask how to send new data on server - maybe you should create web page which ask for local file and it uploads it on server.